# Outlook will not save macro even with correct security option

Tags: vba, email, outlook, office365

I'm trying to implement a simple macro for detecting missing attachments in Outlook 365. The macro runs like a dream, but as soon as I exit the app, it's gone from ThisOutlookSession.

My security setting (which is locked by our IT department) is set to "Warn about all macros", which logically should not prevent the macro from saving or running at startup. I've also put my macro in after Application_Startup, but maybe that's wrong? My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()

End Sub
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

 If InStr(1, Item.Body, "vedhæf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, Item.Subject, "vedhæf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
 If Item.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
 answer = MsgBox("Der er ingen vedhæftning, vil du sende alligevel?", vbYesNo)
 If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
 
 End If
 
 End If

End Sub
```

I've searched far and wide but haven't found an answer to my problem. Anybody have any ideas?

Tried saving in separate module and looking at answers to similar problems, but the "Warning about all macros" option in macro options hasn't been mentioned anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you put your VBA macro. The "Warn about all macros" settings should force Outlook ask users about macros enabled or not. To avoid such circumstances I'd recommend creating a COM add-in which can help to bridge the gap until the same policy is applied to COM add-ins. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

Or consider adjusting the trust center settings to enable VBA macros. For example, you may enable digitally signed VBA macros only and sign your own VBA macro to get it enabled all the time.